# How would I test this statistical hypothesis? (I think Poisson is the right way to go)

Tags: econometrics, poisson-distribution, poisson-regression, change-point

- My company instituted a feature where we stop promoting items listed after X
  hours. And we are interested in how that non-promotion affects the
  amount of “likes” on an item. The hypothesis is that it decreases them.
- But the thing is, likes already decrease over time anyway. So we really want to compare slopes before and after non-promotion.
- For dumb reasons, we can't do a controlled experiment.

If likes are a Poisson process (let's assume), I'd do this:

$$\log(y) = α + \beta_1T + \beta_2X + \beta_3XT + ε,$$

where $y$ = likes per hour,  $T$ = time since posted, $X$ = indicator variable for after X hours (so promotion stops), $XT$ = time since posted * after X hours.

And $\beta_1$ vs $\beta_3$ compares the relative slopes (for log likes) before and after non-promotion.

Does this make sense?

How exacly would you interpret $\beta_1$ vs $\beta_3$ at a non-log level?

Comment: That approach relies heavily on the assumption that log(y) decreases linearly in time.  A nonlinear change will cause you to identify a significant $\beta_3$ even with no real effect of the non-promotion.  Check the model fit carefully.

Comment: I see your point. Is there any version of this equation that would be non-parametric or not have to rely on that assumption? (Though log(y) decreasing linearly in time is equivalent to y decreasing exponentially in time, which seems to fit the data so far)

Comment: The best solution is find a comparison group.  Compare to products that are newly introduced but not promoted, or newly introduced and promoted throughout the observation period.  Without a comparison group you can't avoid heavy reliance on modelling assumptions.